# How not to print empty string from database while editing record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a record in database where are two fields 'leader' and 'checker' are empty. I set it to `NULL` inside sql statement. Then when I want to edit record and press edit record button I got empty string as it is the name. here is the code:

```
<div class="projLeader">
<label>Captain:</label>
<ol>
    <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>  
    <li class="dropClass" name="projLeader"  <?php if (isset($projLeader)) echo 'value="'.$projLeader.'"' ?>><?php echo "<span class='closer'>x</span>".$projLeader.""?></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" />
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="projChecker">
<label>Coordinator:</label>
    <ol>
    <li class="placeholder" name="projChecker"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li> 
    <li class="dropClass" name="projChecker" <?php if (isset($projChecker)) echo 'value="'.$projChecker.'"' ?>><?php echo "<span class='closer'>x</span>".$projChecker."" ?></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="projChecker" class="hiddenListInput2" />
    </ol>
</div>
```

I want to print it only if there is name not just empty string. But even the fields are empty I got [image: this] How can I not to print empty fields?

Comment: use `IS NOT NULL` while get data from database. e.g for `SELECT *
FROM contacts
WHERE name IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: @Karthi It is not the way I want it. If I set WHERE name IS NOT NULL, it wont select the record I want, right? It will look for record which is equal to conditions, but not the record I need.

Comment: explain little more bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IF Else in Php block for Empty or Null value in variable which would set by select query result values. If variable is empty or null then it will not add the list item code. For ex-

```
<div class="projLeader">
<label>Captain:</label>
<ol>
    <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>  
<?php
if (($projLeader != "") && (!is_null($projLeader)) { ?>
    <li class="dropClass" name="projLeader"  <?php if (isset($projLeader)) echo 'value="'.$projLeader.'"' ?>><?php echo "<span class='closer'>x</span>".$projLeader.""?></li>
<?php } ?>  
    <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" />
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I got notice `Notice: Undefined variable: projLeader in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\2version\assign.php on line 702`